# Generate MRTG/RRD like Graphs Performance graphs?

Tags: c#, charts, graph, rrd

I have a database with Performance counter data and i would like to show this on a ASP.net page but the thing is i don't want to use Flash based charting solution or a Javascript based solution i would like to just generate images and use those I want the  images to be like those of RRD or MRTG.

I'm trying to find out how i can create graphs like the following

http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/stream-pop.png
http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/gallery/index.en.html

Any ideas?

Comment: My goal is really just to graph out performance counters as images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a RRD project called [NHawk](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NHawk.aspx) (C# RRDTool Library for .Net and Mono) which is an initiative to provide a thin, complete RRDtool provider for the .Net and Mono framework. More details are available at "[C# Hooks For RRDTool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NHawk.aspx)".

Answer (score 1):

The [RRDtool trunk](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool-trac/browser/trunk/program) now also contains C# bindings for public rrdtool lib functions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up pulling data from the DB and building these charts with [highcharts](http://highcharts.com) their documentation is a perfect example of a great KB.

its probably worth noting that I also implemented the same solution with [jflot](http://code.google.com/p/jsflot/) but was happier with high charts.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this:

http://www.dotnetcharting.com/overview.aspx

Comment: No this is no good... I bought this in the past and was really disappointed with it and their support / documentation.